# MS project parser offsets

Tags: parsing, ms-project

I need help with Microsoft Project. I am writing parser for mpp format and I'm reading it like a ole container, but the problem is I don't really know offsets in storages. I tried hard but I could not find them. Currently I'm working at 2007 version (12).

Answer (score 0):

I look after [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net), which parses the MPP 8, 9, 12 and 14, file formats. You may find it helpful to look at the code used by MPXJ... and you may even find you can use MPXJ anyway rather than writing your own parser.